# What are the differences between the 3 "versions" of "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" by P.R. Halmos?

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

There are 3 versions on amazon:

the 1st one is [published at 1993 Aug, by Springer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387900934), noted "1st ed. 1958. Corr. 2nd printing 1993 edition (August 20, 1993)";

the 2nd one is [published 2014 April by Martino Fine books](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1614272816), remarked "2012 Reprint of 1942 Edition";

the 3rd one is   [published at 2013 by Literacy Licensing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1258812584).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there's much of a difference (apart from one being hardcover and the others paperback).  Without going over all three editions page-by-page, it's hard to say.  The "Corr." indicates that the 1958 edition had some corrections, presumably of errors in the 1942 edition, but I would guess these
are minor typos.